# Getting JSON of Google Places Nearby Search

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to get the result json of a Nearby Search of Google Places API. I'm getting this error : "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource."
The code I'm using is :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      
      var mJson = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyCy639YCvWAzb3Sx0wkMzO5gxG-nHei4QU";
      $.getJSON(mJson,function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Google places test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I even posted the url on jsonlint.com website and it gave me the correct json, but I don't get why it doesn't work on my browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the [Places web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/) api from javascript, use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

Related issues in the issue tracker (marked as "WorkingAsIntended"):

- [Issue 8779:  Google places search API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8779)
- [Issue 8477:  Bug: Place Details API missing CORS header](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8477)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have a json from the nearby places to use it in my own app. I read the link but seems it doesn't give you json and loads the data on a google's map

Comment: Then you will need to proxy the data through your server or see if you can convince google to change that header.

Comment: I tried uploading and testing it from a server and not my local system and the result is the same and I get the same error

Comment: That doesn't sound like a proxy to me.

Comment: Seems I haven't correctly understood your solution, I'll appreciate if you can explain more. Thanks